# How to prevent FireFox from suggestion 'localhost/' over MRU

Tags: firefox

As a web developer I need to access http://localhost:3000 dozens of times a day. Since switching to FireFox, it constantly suggests localhost/ instead. (With Chrome and Safari, I can usually just type "l" and the address I want is suggested first.) I have to type in nearly the entire address before getting the one I want. Can this suggestion be turned off or the priority changed somehow?

[image]

Comment: This is no real answer to your question, but why not creating a bookmark with that address in the toolbar. Just click on it and you are where you wanna be.

Comment: Using the Delete key, you can scroll to and remove any entries you don't want to see.

Comment: With Firefox you can assign keywords to bookmarks. Add the letter `l` to a bookmark for localhost:3000. If you type `l` in your address bar, it will go to localhost:3000.

Comment: @mtak Put that in the form of an answer and I'll mark it Accepted.

Comment: @IAmNaN I've done much more for less rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firefox you can assign keywords to bookmarks. Add the letter l to a bookmark for localhost:3000. If you type l in your address bar, it will go to localhost:3000.

[image: firefox_screenshot]